# Cannot understand this prime generator algorithm in my textbook

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am studying Elements of Programming Interviews, and I am stuck on a problem.
It is about writing a c++ function for finding all prime numbers from 1 to n, for a given n.

```
vector<int> generate_primes_from_1_to_n(const int &n) {
    int size = floor(0.5 * (n - 3)) + 1;
    // is_prime[i] represents (2i+3) is prime or not

    vector<int> primes; // stores the primes from 1 to n

    primes.push_back(2);
    vector<bool> is_prime(size, true);

    for(long i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
       if(is_prime[i]) {
           int p = (i << 1) + 3;
           primes.push_back(p);
           // sieving from p^2, whose index is 2i^2 + 6i + 3
           for (long j = ((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3; j < size; j += p) {
               is_prime[j] = false;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Particularly, I cannot understand the commented 'sieving from p^2, whose index is 2i^2 + 6i + 3' part. For the other parts, I can kind of grasp a rough idea of how they work, but I don't know where this '2i^2 + 6i + 3' comes from, what it does, and how that and its related pieces of codes work.

Can anyone explain this code better?
Thank you.

+

I am getting this output(+'cout's to understand it better)

```
./a.out 100
size is: 49
for i = 0 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 3
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 3
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 6
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 9
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 12
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 15
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 18
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 21
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 24
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 27
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 30
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 33
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 36
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 39
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 42
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 45
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 0 is 48
for i = 1 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 5
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 11
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 16
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 21
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 26
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 31
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 36
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 41
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 46
for i = 2 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 7
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 2 is 23
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 2 is 30
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 2 is 37
((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 2 is 44
for i = 3 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 4 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 11
for i = 5 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 13
for i = 6 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 7 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 17
for i = 8 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 19
for i = 9 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 10 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 23
for i = 11 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 12 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 13 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 29
for i = 14 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 31
for i = 15 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 16 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 17 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 37
for i = 18 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 19 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 41
for i = 20 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 43
for i = 21 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 22 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 47
for i = 23 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 24 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 25 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 53
for i = 26 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 27 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 28 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 59
for i = 29 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 61
for i = 30 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 31 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 32 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 67
for i = 33 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 34 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 71
for i = 35 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 73
for i = 36 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 37 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 38 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 79
for i = 39 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 40 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 83
for i = 41 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 42 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 43 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 89
for i = 44 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 45 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 46 is_prime[i] is 0
for i = 47 is_prime[i] is 1
pushing back p of size 97
for i = 48 is_prime[i] is 0
```

This does not make sense to me, either.

For example, why for p=5, it starts removing it from 11, not 5^2 = 25, in the lines below? 
pushing back p of size 5
 ((i * i) << 1) + 6 * i + 3 for i of 1 is 11

Also, isn't 11 a prime?
It is really confusing.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: There has been a similar discussion on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649068/why-is-sieve-of-eratosthenes-more-efficient-than-the-simple-dumb-algorithm

Comment: Could you paste your full, working code in pastebin?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Algorithm

The algorithm used by your prime generator code is called "Sieve of Eratosthenes". In general, it creates a list of numbers, and iterates over the list. All multiplications of the current number are removed from the list, and the remaining numbers are prime.

For example, let us consider `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`. We encounter 2, so we remove all even numbers from the list:

```
[2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]
```

Same for 3:

```
[2,3,5,7,11,13]
```

`5`, `7`, `11` and `13` have no multiplications in the list, so we remove nothing and remain with a list of primes.

### Visual example

[image]

In this example (courtesy of Wikipedia), all multiplications of 2, 3 and 5 were removed from the list - multiplications of 2 were painted pink, multiplication of 3 were painted in green, and multiplications of 5 in dark blue. 7 will be iterated next, so it's highlighted. The dark colored numbers are prime, the light colored numbers are not prime, and the gray numbers have net yet been reached.

### Optimizations in your code

As mentioned by @BenJackson, your code is optimized twice:

- Firstly, it only stores odd numbers only starting from 3, because we know that even numbers are not prime (except 2).
- Secondly, for the number p, it only starts to sieve from p². This is correct because if `n<p` then `n*p` was already sieved when multiplications of `n` were sieved.

This is the reason why the cryptic comment:

```
// sieving from p^2, whose index is 2i^2 + 6i + 3
```

Suppose that our algorithm has reached the second item in the vector, therefore `i=2`. The number in question is 5, because the index `i` denotes the number `2i+3` (first optimization).

We should sieve all multiplications of `5` from `25` onwards. The index that represents `25` is `11`, because `25=2*11+3`. Following your printouts, it removes indices `11, 16, 21, 26, ...`, which correspond to the numbers `25, 35, 45, 55, ..` - all odd multiplications of 5 we'd like to remove.

You can read more about it at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SieveofEratosthenes.html), and there's a nice [javascript on-line demonstration here](http://www.hbmeyer.de/eratosiv.htm).

Comment: a side note: `p=2i+3, p^2=4i^2+12i+9, (p^2-3)/2 = 2i^2+6i+3`. I prefer `p=2i+1`, the value/index translation formulas are nicer.

Answer (score 8):

The table of primes only stores odd values starting at 3 (obviously even values cannot be prime).  The relation is given in the line `int p = (i << 1) + 3`, or `p = 2i + 3`.  Now solve that for `i`, getting `i = (p - 3)/2`.  Now what `i` corresponds to `p^2`?  Plug in `(2i+3)^2` to that second formula and simplify.  Now you have the `i` for `p^2` in terms of the `i` for `p`.

Example:  Let's say `i=1`, thus the entry `is_prime[i]` is a test of the prime `p=2i+3`, or `p=5`.  So yes, it is prime.  Now the seive (explained elsewhere) wants to start marking non-primes at 25.  It needs to know what `i` corresponds to 25.  Now you could simply compute `p*p` and then insert that into `i=(p-3)/2` and get `j=11`.  The code has skipped those intermediate steps (as I showed above) to compute `j=2i^2+6i+3` and gotten `j=11` directly.

Comment: I still do not understand. For i = 0, j is 3, for i = 1, j is 11, and for i = 2, j is 23. None of j is a square of any number(p)! Am I getting wrong j? Or Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2418202 for i=1, the number in question is `5` (`1*2+3=5`). We should sieve from 25. The index of 25, denoted by `j`, is 11 (`2^2+6+3=4+6+3=11`).

Comment: +1 Ben - nice answer! It's not a bug, because removing "every OTHER multiple of `p`" means that we only remove odd multiples. For example, we only need to remove `25, 35, 45, 55, ...` for 5, because `30, 40, 50, ...` were optimized away by picking only odd numbers for the prime array.

Answer (score 1):

Lines like these:

```
vector<int> generate_primes_from_1_to_n(const int &n) {
    int size = floor(0.5 * (n - 3)) + 1;
```

...

```
for(long i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
   if(is_prime[i]) {
       int p = (i << 1) + 3;
```

are a 'hack' so that the potential prime numbers 3, 5, 7, etc can be iterated over by iterating 0, 1, 2, 3 in `i` and using `p` for the corresponding possible primes 3, 5, 7, 9, etc.

It's a basic prime sieve other than that.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, *i* maps array locations and *p* maps the numbers that those array locations represent, according to the formula *p* = 2 *i* + 1. It may be easier to think about if you keep *i* and *p* explicitly in the program:

```
function primes(n)
    m := floor((n-1)/2)
    sieve := makeArray(0..m-1, True)
    i := 0; p := 3; ps := [2]
    while p * p <= n
        if sieve[i]
            append p to ps
            j := (p*p - 3) / 2
            while j < m
                sieve[j] := False
                j := j + p
        i := i + 1; p := p + 2
    while i < m
        if sieve[i]
            append p to ps
        i := i + 1; p := p + 2
    return ps
```

The strange formula for *j* in the original code is formed by taking the formula for *j* shown above and rewriting in terms of *i* instead of *p*.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I have an [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog that, among other things, discusses this exact formula in some depth.